# Traverse upto leaf node iOS in Tree Structure TableView

Tags: ios, ipad, tree-traversal, qtreeview, tree-structure

I am stuck at the point where I want to delete the particular Row Object from table but **It is dynamic tree structure** means object can be created, deleted, reordered, etc at any time using all the Table methods.

Tree Structure is dynamic so How to reach to the **Leaf Object** OR **Intermediate Object** which need to deleted.
   **Traverse in all the Branches as well**.

Here It can be any number of nodes, child nodes, parent nodes. But I need to Traverse all the nodes upto all the **Leaf nodes** .

So, my question is to **delete any node?**

If you have ideas, suggestions about this problem so your solutions accepted.

Thanks in Advance.

Tree Example as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the `TapGesture` to tableviewCell then you will get the tap point to find out `indexPath` of currentCell.

Accordingly you can easily find out the current cell you selected.

Let me know if you need it in more detail.

Comment: No I don't want to selection for that. I have created that Row selection and Deletion code. 
But what happen when I have tree length from ROOT to LEAF NODE is 10.
I want to delete "Green" colored background cell. so what should I do.

Should I need to Traverse the whole Array OR How can I determine that "Green" colored cell is whose child?

Comment: You can create a class structure so that each object has info of its child or parents. If the data is less you can directly check by traversing array

Comment: @krunal how did you manage to load this Data into a UITableView? IN my case, the data can go up to n number of nodes. How did you traverse along this data set?

Comment: @Nil You have 2 ways to load data into Table. 1) Flat Array which have child-parent relationship using Specific Identifier. So when you have find a particular row is a child of a parent then you can set indentation level property of TableView. 2) Nested Array using RA TreeView Third Party Library where you can find all kind of examples and idea as well.